# How to calculate total results of combinations of letters

Tags: permutations

I am programmer and have developed an algorithm to run a processor intensive function on all the permutations of 2 letters (X and O) when we define how many X's and O's there will be.

For example, I may run `F(10, 5)` which would run all the permutations of length 15 with 10 X's and 5 O's. If I ran `F(4,5)` it would run all the permutations of length 9 with 4 X's and 5 O's. *See below for example*
                                                                                                                                                                                                        I did quite a bit of research, and everything I found to calculate this would allow for any amount of X's or O's. That formula would be `2^n` where N is the total length. This is not what I need because I specify the amount of X's and O's.

I also found the `n! / (n - r)!r!` formula but that is completely wrong because I have a defined length.

I also found "derangement" but have no clue what I am looking at or how to apply it to my use case (if it even applies). [Derangement on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html)

The reason I want to calculate the total number is so I can give a progress bar and estimated time remaining. Obviously this is not needed, but I am running permutations like `F(10,20)` which has millions, if not billions of permutations and they can take quite a long time. It would be great to know how far and how many left there are to run.

I am at a loss as to how to come up with the formula needed. Maybe it is obvious and you can just point out something obvious I am missing. I thought I may try to use `2^N - (all the permutations of 2^N which do not have the correct number)` but then I am back to original problem with trying to figure how many permutations do not have the correct number.

I can post the entire algorithm I use to calculate all the possible permutations if that would assist in coming up with a formula to calculate the total number of permutations.

### Example Data

If I run `F(2, 3)` it would run:

```
XXOOO
XOXOO
OXXOO
XOOXO
OXOXO
OOXXO
XOOOX
OXOOX
OOXOX
OOOXX
```

So, `F(2, 3)` has 10 permutations.

If I run `F(3, 3)` it would run:

```
XXXOOO
XXOXOO
XOXXOO
OXXXOO
XXOOXO
XOXOXO
OXXOXO
XOOXXO
OXOXXO
OOXXXO
XXOOOX
XOXOOX
OXXOOX
XOOXOX
OXOXOX
OOXXOX
XOOOXX
OXOOXX
OOXOXX
OOOXXX
```

So, `F(3, 3)` has 20 permutations.

Comment: The formula you rejected is correct. In your notation, $F(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$.  There are other equivalent versions which may be computationally more convenient.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: The rest of your question is quite interesting. I think of it as finding a way of listing the permutations of $a$ X's and $b$ O's in a systematic way so that you have a "nice" estimate of how far a particular permutation is in the list. I believe I have seen such nice enumerations. I hope that someone knowledgeable about such things will give an answer that lets you produce a good "progress bar.'

Comment: The output you see in the example data is the output from the actual algorithm. I plugged in the formula and it worked! I am showing estimated time left now and all is good. Thank you again so much!

Comment: Now that you know how to compute the total count $|F(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)!}{a!\,b!}$, could you simply add a running count and consider the ratio (running count)/(total count)?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius That is what I did.